# Handle indexedDB versioning

Tags: javascript, store, indexeddb

I have a page that contains data based on which ID is receiving, for some business logic I need to store those values into an indexDB.

This is my code from loadData page

```
await createIndexDB(querystringID);
```

And this is what I use to create the indexDB:

```
const createIndexDB= async (ID) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let isTrueInit = false;

        var dbReq = indexedDB.open('myindexDB', 1);

        dbReq.onerror = (e) => {
            myDB = dbReq.result
            myDB.close()
            reject({
                status: 'error',
                message: dbReq.error,
            })
        }

        dbReq.onsuccess = (event) => {
            const storeName = 'myindexDB' + ID;
            myDB = dbReq.result
            if (!myDB.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
                myDB.close()
                isTrueInit = true
                reject({
                    status: 'upgradeneeded',
                    message: "Store doesn't exist",
                    upgradeNeeded: true,
                    version: dbReq.result.version,
                    isTrueInit,
                })
            } else {
                myDB.onversionchange = (e) => {
                    // Close immediately to allow the upgrade requested by another
                    // instance to proceed.
                    myDB.close()
                }
                resolve({
                    db: myDB,
                    isTrueInit,
                })
            }
        }

        dbReq.onupgradeneeded = () => {
            const storeName = 'myindexDB' + ID;
            myDB = dbReq.result;
            if (!myDB.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) isTrueInit = true
            myDB.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: 'itemid', autoIncrement: true })
        }

    });
}
```

Then, on the loadData page I execute some function to retrieve, set and delete items from the indexDB, to do that I use something like this:

```
await getAllIndexDBItem(querystringID);

const getAllIndexDBItem = async (ID) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var myDB = null;
        var dbReq = indexedDB.open('myindexDB', 1);

        dbReq.onsuccess = function (e) {
            myDB= dbReq.result;
            const transaction = myDB.transaction(['myindexDB' + ID], 'readonly');
            const store = transaction.objectStore('myindexDB' + ID);

            let request = store.getAll();

            request.onsuccess = event => {
                const result = request ? request.result : null;
                resolve(result);
            };

            transaction.onerror = event => {
                console.log('error getting element from myindexDB' + event.target.error);
                reject('error getting element from myindexDB ' + event.target.error);
            };

            transaction.oncomplete = event => {

            };
        }
    });
}
```

Everything it's working with the first ID that I sent to loadData page, creates the indexDB and the object, but when I sent another ID to loadData page I get the upgradeneeded error message. If I change this:

```
var dbReq = indexedDB.open('myindexDB', 1);
```

To:

```
var dbReq = indexedDB.open('myindexDB', 2);
```

Now it works okay with the two different IDs. So my question is, what can I do to handle the indexDB versioning properly instead of changing manually the version? Taking into consideration that sometimes the indexDB will not exists yet.

Answer (score 1):

The short but unhelpful answer is "you're doing it wrong". You should only change the schema (add/delete object stores) when your code and hence your logic requirements for the database are changing.

Rather than thinking about separate object stores per ID, a more typical approach is to include the ID in the store's keys. For example, use `[ID, other_key]` as the key structure in your stores - a compound key with the ID you are partitioning by, and whatever other key(s) you were planning to use.

Another option would be to use an entirely different *database* per ID, with a unique name per database. Each such database would be an identical schema. e.g. make the open call `open('myDB-' + ID)`, and use the same store name in each database.